# Unable to retrieve the query string from jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, query-string

In my jsp, I have links to another jsp page with query string in it. I hovered over the link and all information is correct.

```
<a href='/ph.jsp?albumid=${album.id}'>Click me</a>
```

I have mapped ph to my PHServlet. Inside the servlet, I tried to retrieve the query string albumid.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String albumId = req.getParameter("albumid");
    req.setAttribute("albumid", albumId);

    getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ph.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

In my ph.jsp, the page displayed "Album: " instead. There is also no exception happened.

```
Album: <c:out value="${albumid}" />
```

I have no idea where went wrong. Any helps?

I have done some testing and I suspect when I clicked the link, the servlet is being not executed at all. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve after multiple testings. I found out the main reason is that I have put ph.jsp instead of ph as my mapping is created with ph only.

```
<a href='/ph?albumid=${album.id}'>Click me</a>
```

By changing that, it will load my servlet before loading my jsp page. And all data is being retrieved and displayed.